# Convergence of a $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(2z-1+i)^n}{1-\log{\sqrt[4]{n}}}$ on the boundary

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I have the following complex power-series:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(2z-1+i)^n}{1-\log{\sqrt[4]{n}}}.$$

It converges in $\{z:|2z-1+i|<1\}$. I'm not quite understand how to investigate its behaviour on the boundary $|2z-1+i|=1$, but I've tried to substitute $(2z-1+i)$ with $e^{i\varphi}$ and use Euler's identity:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i\varphi n}}{1-\log{\sqrt[4]{n}}}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\sin(\varphi n)}{1-\log{\sqrt[4]{n}}}+i \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(\varphi n)}{1-\log{\sqrt[4]{n}}}. $$

As far as I understand, if $\varphi \neq 0$ this two series converge due to Dirichlet's test. But Wolfram Alpha shows convergence only at the point $z=\frac{-i}{2}$ or $\varphi=\pi$. So where did i go wrong?

Comment: What you are calling a power series isn't a power series. Have you left out the summation in that first display?

Comment: Yes, I've accidentally didn't write the summation, but now I've fixed it.

Comment: Consider the possibility that it's Wolfy who's wrong.

Comment: I think there's a lot of distracting terms there. The behavior on the boundary should be the same as for $\sum_2^{\infty}(z^n/\log n)$. Why not try that, and see what happens?

Comment: Making any progress?